# How to display the supported services of Bluetooth in tableview from devicename(UITableViewCell)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5, core-bluetooth

I'm developing Bluetooth app.I have a name of available Bluetooth device in Table View..If press a device means i want to know all the supported services UUID name in another view controller with Table view.Give me an Idea.

1)Peripheralmanager (NSObject)

2)FirstViewController (In this I have a Device Name)

3)SecondViewController (In this I want Supported Services)

Peripheralmanager.m

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central 
didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral 
 advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData 
              RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

    NSLog(@"didDiscoverPeriphera.peripheral: %@ rssi: %@, UUID:%@ advertisementData:%@", peripheral,RSSI,peripheral.UUID, [advertisementData description]);

   targetPeripheral = peripheral;
   peripheral.delegate = self;
if (!peripheral.isConnected)
{
   [centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}
```

}

FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)peripheralManagerDidConnectPeripheral:(PeripheralManager *)peripheral
{
   NSLog(@"%@",peripheral.deviceName);
   NSLog(@"%@",peripheral.rssi);
   [device addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",peripheral.deviceName]];  
   [self.deviceTable reloadData];
}
```

Tableview

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier=@"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
   if(cell==nil)
{
   cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
   cell.textLabel.text=[device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


}
```

If you want more information Please Ask me.

Please Check this Link [sample Itunes app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue/id557428110?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4)

image
[image]

[image]

Comment: did you find the answer I am trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Well...
First of all, you want Bluetooth Low Energy, which is quite different from the bluetooth. Even if the framework is called Bluetooth and the "normal one" is called ExternalAccessory.
Right ?

I am not sure of what is really your question.
Did you try the sample of Apple: CoreBluetooth Temperature Sensor ? Or even the two samples (temperature and heart monitor) works too since they uses the same framework.
It will explain to you all it works : Peripheral > Service > Characteristic.